# Deleting rest of the columns after a certain column in transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a 3 table with columns Col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7,col8........col56
I want to delete all the columns in all the tables after Col4 dynamically.

I know below query doesn't make sense as there are large number of columns

Alter table 
Drop column Col5, col6, col7,....,Col56

Can somebody please suggest any alternate method that I could implement to accomplish this in MS-SQL.

Comment: You can create a dynamic sql statement starting from metadata in system view  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Answer (score 2):

***Assuming*** that you only have columns called `Col1`, `Col2`, ... `Col56`, and that are in the "correct" order (ascending my numerical value) you could do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (Col1 int,
                        Col3 int,
                        Col4 int,
                        Col5 int,
                        Col6 int,
                        Col7 int,
                        Col8 int,
                        Col9 int,
                        Col10 int);
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.YourTable;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'YourTable';

SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DROP COLUMN ' + 
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME)
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                  WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                    AND C.ORDINAL_POSITION > 4
                    --AND C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE N'Col%' --uncomment if needed
                  ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N';';
PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.YourTable;

GO
DROP TABLE YOurTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3b89679fa503a491215fcdefe4e1dc1)

Comment: Worked Perfect @Larnu! How can I loop this operation through multiple tables. In  my original question, I have three tables in place and all three tables are present in the same database. But the number of these tables might change. Is there a way to accomplish this. I learnt that cursors can help me do this, but I am not understanding the application of cursors here. Any help is greatly appreciated @Larnu .

Comment: You could change `C.TABLE_NAME = @TableName` to `C.TABLE_NAME IN ('Table1','Table2',....)` and then `QUOTENAME(@TableName)` to `QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME)` . That should work.